# I'm not able to cache my PHP rewritten CSS file

Tags: php

I have a php file that is renamed in htaccess as a css file. The reason being, is because I have some styles and colors which change based on some admin options.

Anyway, I am trying to allow a visitor's browser to cache the file. Here's what I have:

style.php:

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

// Start normal CSS styles...
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^assets/css/min/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)\.css$ assets/css/min.php?style=$1&layout=$2&ver=$3 [L,QSA]

# Compress
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css

# Cache for 1 week
<FilesMatch ".(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"

</IfModule>
```

In the page head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/assets/css/min/blue/flat/0.9.2.css">
```

Each time a new page is loaded, the page contents are requested. These are the headers I receive:

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 13881
Content-Type: text/css; charset: UTF-8;charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 20 Feb 2016 22:49:17 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=94
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.12 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.12
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's something to do with the fact that (internally, once rewritten) the URL has a query string so isn't getting cached, although the docs for Apache 2.4 state 'Ordinarily, requests with query string parameters are cached separately for each unique query string. This is according to RFC 2616/13.9 done only if an expiration time is specified.' & you appear to be setting an expiration time - is mod_expires definitely enabled?

Comment: @RobGudgeon Yes, mod_expires is enabled because it works for some other type of files I have (images).

Comment: does your "access plus 1 week" fire for standard, non-rewritten CSS files?

Comment: this line also looks weird, from the headers: `Content-Type: text/css; charset: UTF-8;charset=UTF-8` - try dropping your `; charset: UTF-8` from the php script's header - I wonder if this is tripping up Apache when trying to detect content-type

Comment: @RobGudgeon Thank you for your suggestions. I removed `charset: UTF-8` from the script's header and it removed the duplicate charset in the headers. Also, I tried a non-rewritten CSS file, and it caches those- just not this one that's rewritten.

Comment: only thing I can think of trying is dropping the query string from the rewritten URL & see if that helps. Obviously won't meet your needs as a solution, but at least it'd narrow down whether it's the query string causing it, or something else (e.g. php itself causing the no-cache headers)

Comment: or you could try adding the cache-control headers to the php script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mod_expires config applies to files based on their mimetype as perceived by the webserver. Unless you've done some major surgery on the webserver config elsewhere, the webserver will not associate the text/CSS mimetype with files ending in .php (and if it did, much further hacking would be required to get them processed by the PHP parser). The header set by your PHP script is irrelevant to this process.

While it is possible to force mod_expires to add caching headers to the response, you'll also have to use mod_headers to *remove* the values PHP sets; when a browsers receives multiple conflicting caching instructions, it will resort to the shortest expiry time expressed in them.

Hence, to make the content cacheable, you should emit the caching information directly from the PHP script. E.g.

```
header('Cache-control: max-age=604800; private');
```

But basing the expiry time on the access time is not the best solution.

Comment: I tried adding that to the PHP script an there was no change in the headers received and the file was still not cached.

Comment: Then you weren't setting the right headers. Post a new question with the PHP code and the headers you got.

Comment: I just realized if I added `header('Pragma: cache')`, the file caches fine. I don't know where that header is coming form, but that is what was stopping it from caching.

Comment: In what browser? Where in the specs does it mention "pragma" as a response header, let alone define its action?

Comment: I'm using Firefox. I have no idea where that header came from.